# How is complex systems research interacting with AI research?

Tags: complexity-theory

Because future AI may produce emergent phenomena, and because these are probably gaps in our current understanding of this, it feels like complex systems may be an increasingly important research field.

Unless there is some kind of commonality of emergent behaviour (or aspects of complex systems more generally) it seems that future AI systems may behave in ways very difficult to predict. Potentially complex system research of the brain could help in artificial neural network understanding but because of the diversity of the latter this may be a loose similarity. Further, this may or may not hold for other types of AI.

The main question is from a basic educational level, how does complex systems research affect AI and vice vera. Possible subquestions (whatever helps understanding of this topic better): Is there much research at the intersection of AI and complex systems (so someone like Melanie Mitchell)? What kinds of things may complex systems research inform AI? Is AI now helping us understand AI better?

Comment: This seems like more of a discussion question, so I'm not sure it's a good fit for ai.stackexchange.

Comment: I don't really see the connection between complex systems and machine learning except in a broad sense. Anything with multiple parts that interact in nontrivial ways can be said to be a complex system, so things such as GAN, autonomous vehicles can certainly be called complex systems. However complex systems research deals with topics like swarms/collective behavior, which aren't really relevant to machine learning.

Comment: The question in this post is not really clear. You mention Melanie Mitchell - can you give an example of one of her papers that you think is at the intersection of AI and complex systems.

Comment: Ballpark would be something like the 1993 Revisiting the edge of chaos: Evolving cellular automata to perform computations.

Comment: @Taw: Swarms and collective behavior are topics of AI. For examples see papers presented at the International Conference on Intelligent Systems, Metaheuristics & Swarm Intelligence (ISMSI) http://www.ismsi.org/.

Comment: Revisiting the Edge of Chaos: Evolving Cellular Automata to Perform Computations,
Melanie Mitchell, Peter T. Hraber, and James P. Crutchfield, https://arxiv.org/pdf/adap-org/9303003.pdf